# Show query progress

Tags: sql, jdbc

I want show the process of long running jdbc query.Is it possible?

If the total result of the query is of 100 records and if am retrieving 10 records at a time, then after retrieving first 10 records, is it possible to know that 90% is remaining?

Thanks in advance

Comment: do a count before, yes

Answer (score 0):

try to decrement your progress bar by 10,  That should fix the  problem

```
//something like that 
 if (progressBar1.Value < progressBar1.Maximum - 1)
            {
                progressBar1.Increment(2);
                progressBar1.Increment(-1);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have Found this code. This may work pretty well

SELECT r.session_id,r.command,CONVERT(NUMERIC(6,2),r.percent_complete)
AS [Percent Complete],CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),DATEADD(ms,r.estimated_completion_time,GetDate()),20) AS [ETA Completion Time],
CONVERT(NUMERIC(10,2),r.total_elapsed_time/1000.0/60.0) AS [Elapsed Min],
CONVERT(NUMERIC(10,2),r.estimated_completion_time/1000.0/60.0) AS [ETA Min],
CONVERT(NUMERIC(10,2),r.estimated_completion_time/1000.0/60.0/60.0) AS [ETA Hours],
CONVERT(VARCHAR(1000),(SELECT SUBSTRING(text,r.statement_start_offset/2,
CASE WHEN r.statement_end_offset = -1 THEN 1000 ELSE (r.statement_end_offset-r.statement_start_offset)/2 END)
FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle)))
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests r WHERE command IN ('RESTORE DATABASE','BACKUP DATABASE')